# bind relational data to view in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models: **Company** and **Person**. A company has many people and a person belongs to a company. I'm trying to represent this in the UI. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to bind relational data to the view though.

Here is my Person model

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({

  firstName: DS.attr('string'),

  lastName: DS.attr('string'),

  city: DS.attr('string'),

  state: DS.attr('string'),

  email: DS.attr('string'),

  company: DS.belongsTo('company'),

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

Here is my Company model

```
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({

  name: DS.attr('string'),

  people: DS.hasMany('person')

});
```

Here is my route

```
App.Router.map(function() {

    this.resource('people', function() {

        this.resource('person', { path: ':person_id'});

        this.route('new');
    });
});

App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {

        return this.store.find('person', params.person_id);
    }
});
```

And here is my view

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='show/_edit'>
<div>
  <form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    {{input type="text" value=firstName class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name"}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    {{input type="text" value=lastName class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    {{input type="email" value=email class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email"}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    {{input type="text" value=city class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City"}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="state">State</label>
    {{input type="text" value=state class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="state"}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <span>{{company.name}}</span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Done</button>
</form>

</div>
```

A request is never issued to `companies/2` though. Do i need to return an RSVP hash of both the person and their company in the router to accommodate this?

Here is the returned json from `/people/` https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7632294

Comment: Your sample seems correct, can you show the json returned from the server?

Comment: sure, before i get to the single record route i get a list of people. This is the returned json from that response https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7632294

Comment: I answered your question, I think that your problem is with your company property name. If you are using rails with active model serializers, you can use the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `RESTAdapter` you need to change the `company_id: "1"` to `company: "1"`.